# Javascript API Google Maps set Center right of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a container to render a google map instance, above this container i draw (HTML) another container with a search box (Origin and Destination).

When an origin is selected, a marker is draw in the map (the same with the Destination input).

Now i need to "pan" the map to show the markers in the right side of the search box.

Now, when i put a marker i use fitbounds to make sure the marker is inside the map container, but in some occasions, the marker is draw under the searchbox.

Then i try to use "panBy" method to draw the center of the map in the right side of searchbox, but don't always work.

How can i make sure that the two markers always be visible and draw in the right side of search box?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: You need to make sure that the marker is in the right side of the map. If we get the NE coordinates along with the center, we can compare that with the marker position and easily set a new center as  required.

Code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var markerPos = this.getPosition(), center = map.getCenter(),
        mapNE = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();

    if(!(markerPos.lng() > center.lng() && markerPos.lng() < mapNE.lng())) { //marker is not on the right side
        //based on center and NE calulate pos to center the marker
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(markerPos.lat(), (markerPos.lng() - (mapNE.lng() - center.lng())/2)));
    }
});
```